# create the program more efficient

Tags: java

problem,

- return "a" if number x can be divided by 3
- return "b" if number x can be divided by 5
- return "ab" if number x can be divided by 3 and 5

my Solution

```
 if(x mod 3 ==0 ) return "a"
 else if (x mod 3 == 0) return "b"
 else if (x mod 3 == 0 && x mod 5) return "ab"
```

is there any other efficient solution than this?

Comment: This question is misguided.  The chances are that performance is *irrelevant* in this code.  Correctness is certainly more important.

Comment: (And ... if you haven't cottoned on yet ... your solution is incorrect, according to most peoples' understanding of that "spec".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iff ((x mod 3 == 0) and (x mod 5 == 0)) <=> (x mod 15 == 0)

```
if (x mod 15 == 0) return "ab"    
else if(x mod 3 == 0 ) return "a"
else if (x mod 5 == 0) return "b"
```

Answer (score 2):

to save few computations:

```
boolean mod3 = x mod 3 == 0
boolean mod5 = x mod 5 == 0
if (mod3 && mod5) return "ab"
if (mod3) return "a"
if (mod5) return "b"
```

Comment: This approach should be the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

A marginally more efficient ... and definitely more CORRECT ... solution is:

```
 if (x mod 3 == 0) {
    if (x mod 5 == 0) {
        return "ab"
    } else {
        return "a"
    }
 } else if (x mod 5 == 0) {
    return "b";
 } else {
    // probably ...
    return "";
 }
```

Note that the difference in performance is most likely insignificant, and it is quite possible that it is zero ... if the JIT compiler is smart enough.  This applies to *all* of the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
 if (x mod 3 == 0 && x mod 5 == 0) return "ab"    
 else if(x mod 3 ==0 ) return "a"
 else if (x mod 5 == 0) return "b"
```

otherwise "ab" will not be returned even though the number is divisible by both 3 and 5

Comment: still a problem: there is no x mod 5

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
String result = "";
if (x mod 3 == 0) result += "a";
if (x mod 5 == 0) result += "b";

return result;
```

But it has the overhead of string concatenation

Answer (score 0):

```
string result = ""
if(x mod 3 == 0 )
{
    result += "a"
}
if(x mod 5 == 0 )
{
    result += "b"
}

return result;
```

This approach checks the modulo by 3 and 5 only once.

Answer (score 0):

This is the classical [FizzBuzz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz)  problem you should always consider 
the first case being the common divider while then proceed in descending order
like this :

```
 if (x mod 3 == 0 && x mod 5) return "ab"    
 else if(x mod 5 ==0 ) return "b"
 else if (x mod 3 == 0) return "a"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   String result="";
   result=(x%3 == 0 && x%5 == 0 ? "ab" : x%5 == 0 ? "a" : x%3 == 0 ? "b" : "not divisible to any number" );
   System.out.println(result);
```